# Octopus Azure Deployment failing on Array patameter

Tags: azure, octopus-deploy

Array type parameter in ARM template fails while deploying through Octopus

This is the snapshot of my arm template where I declared the parameter

```
"databaseArray" : {
  "type": "array",
  "defaultValue": [],
  "metadata" : {
      "description": "Object Array of databaseName / tier / SKU / backup"
  }
}
```

Here is my variable declaration in Octopus.

Variable Name: `App.Databases`

Variable value: `[{"databaseName": "core","tier": "Standard","SKU": "S1","backup": true}, {"databaseName": "web","tier": "Standard","SKU": "S1","backup": true}]`

I keep on getting this below error

*Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: d. Path 'databaseArray.value', line 1, position 666. 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.Skip() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetExtensionData(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonReader reader, String memberName, Object o) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Azure.Deployment.Integration.ResourceGroups.ResourceGroupTemplateNormalizer.Normalize(String json) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Azure.Deployment.Conventions.DeployAzureResourceGroupConvention.Install(RunningDeployment deployment) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunInstallConventions() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunConventions() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
Running rollback conventions... 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: d. Path 'databaseArray.value', line 1, position 666. 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.Skip() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetExtensionData(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonReader reader, String memberName, Object o) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Azure.Deployment.Integration.ResourceGroups.ResourceGroupTemplateNormalizer.Normalize(String json) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Azure.Deployment.Conventions.DeployAzureResourceGroupConvention.Install(RunningDeployment deployment) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunInstallConventions() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunConventions() 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Azure.Commands.DeployAzureResourceGroupCommand.Execute(String[] commandLineArguments) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Error
   at Calamari.Program.Execute(String[] args) 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Fatal
The remote script failed with exit code 100 
October 29th 2019 19:32:53Fatal
The action Deploy Databases on Azure Melbourne failed*

Anyone faced the same problem before? Please help

Comment: What version of Octopus are you using? Potentially, you're hitting [this issue](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/3198) which was fixed in 2019.1.6.
Otherwise, you might want to reach out to us at https://octopus.com/support and we'll help you out.
-Matt (Octopus)

Comment: @MattRichardson I am using v2018.4.12

Comment: In which case, I'd suggest an upgrade to get that fix.

Comment: Thanks@Matt Richardson. Will pass this to Octopus admin.